# grails resource tags creating duplicate app context in link

Tags: tomcat, grails

At times, our code has a need to create links for resources.  When this happens,  it looks like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="${resource(dir: '/css/', file: 'UXdashboard-pdf.css') }"
media="all"/>
```

However, this creates a link that looks like the following (note the duplicate app context)

```
<link href="/ici/ici/css/UXdashboard-pdf.css" media="all"
```

We do not have grails.serverUrl or grails.app.context defined. We do have app.name='ici' set in application.properties.

We deploy using tomcat set up with autodeploy="true" which should create an application context of 'ici' based on the war file name.

I am not sure where the second app-context is coming from. Should I not be setting app.name in application.properties?  I could specify the 'base' parameter, but I would prefer to understand exactly where the duplicate context is coming from before I try to work around it.

We use apache as our front end document server, and apache seems to be able to handle these links as I see 200 codes returned for them.  But we have a plugin that does pdf generation, and I suspect that it is not finding the css file because of the link.

thanks!

Comment: so what happens if with dir :'css' also ather than that link <g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" /> http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/ref/Tags/resource.html

Comment: Excellent idea.  The following tags:

Comment: <g:resource dir="css" file = "UXdashboard-pdf.css" /> 
 <g:resource dir="css"  contextPath= "/ici" file = "UXdashboard-pdf.css"/> <g:resource dir="css"  base="http:/devici1.innocentive.com/ici/" file = "UXdashboard-pdf.css" />   produced the following results: /ici/ici/css/UXdashboard-pdf.css
/ici/ici/css/UXdashboard-pdf.css
/icip:/devici1.innocentive.com/ici//css/UXdashboard-pdf.css
/ici/ici/css/UXdashboard-pdf.css
<g:resource dir="css" file = "UXdashboard-pdf.css" />

Comment: The very interesting one is the resource tag that contains the base.  In that case, the first three characters of http: are overwritten with /ici.  <g:resource dir="css"  base="http:/devici1.innocentive.com/ici/" file = "UXdashboard-pdf.css" />  produced /icip:/devici1.innocentive.com/ici//css/UXdashboard-pdf.css

Comment: <g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" base="ttp://admin.mygreatsite.com"/> == ttp://admin.mygreatsite.com/css/main.css http://beta.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually answering my own question in case someone else runs into this situation.  It turns out that the double `/<appcontext>/<appcontext>`  is caused by grails.resources.uri.prefix ="ici".

We also use the Resources plugin, which is integrated with the g:resource tag.  The resources plugin automatically adds a /static/ directory when forming its urls. We don't use a static subdirectory and grails.resources.uri.prefix allows one to override it.  Just setting it to the empty string didn't work, but apache can handle the `<appcontext>/<appcontext>`.  So all I need to do in the pdf generation case is rewrite this one link.